# How can I fix framerate Issues with Yuri's Revenge that I am not getting in Red Alert 2?

Tags: command-and-conquer-red-alert-2, command-and-conquer-yuris-revenge

So I got *Command and Conquer The First Decade* and completed all of *Red Alert 2* getting all the Par times except for one mission and figured it was about time I went onto to play Yuri's Revenge.

When I went to do the Allied Missions there was some really noticeable framerate issues from the start, especially after the timeshift when one of the Dreadnoughts blew up the bridge. It was like 1 Frame/10 seconds as the bridge blew up. At first I thought this might have been just the first mission because it had that weird time warp effect but it's doing it in the second mission as well.

Now the graphics settings of Yuri's Revenge is matched to what I had for Red Alert 2. High Quality and 1024 x 768 resolution and Red Alert 2 played perfectly so I toned these down to their lowest setting for Yuri's Revenge but it made no difference as there appears to be lag with the mouse cursor.

I have tried:

- Adding `VideoBackBuffer=No` to RA2MD.ini as suggested [here](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Command_%26_Conquer:_Red_Alert_2#Lag.2Flow_FPS)
- Created a shortcut, set compatibility mode to Windows 98 and disabled everything.
- Made an image of the CD to load it with Deamon Tools to elimiate the possibility that my DVD Drive is too slow.
- Downloaded a No CD Crack to eliminate the use of the CD itself.

None of these has had any sort of effect.

I am running this on Windows 7 64-bit and I have about 2GB of ram. I'm not entirely sure what my graphics card is, however Red Alert 2 played perfectly on max settings.

How can I fix these framerate issues Yuri's Revenge is having?